# Swift 3.0 token expire how will be call the token automatically?

Tags: ios, swift, token, access-token

Once the token is received, when the token is over, then how can I call the token automatically after the login? on same page

```
 Alamofire.request(urlString, method: .post, parameters: newPost, encoding: JSONEncoding.default)
        .responseJSON { response in

            if let json = response.result.value as? [String : Any]{
                print("JSON: \(json)")
                if UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "logged_in") {

                    Token = json["Token"]! as! String

                    UserDefaults.standard.set(Token, forKey: "Token")
                    UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()

                }

            } else {
                print("Did not receive json")
            }

            //expectation.fulfill()
    }
```

Comment: You could create your own method for all the requests (all you calls should be done with this one), and when you find the error is because of invalid token, redo the token call, and on success, redo the previous request.?

Comment: make one function and call when ever you want

Comment: @BHAVIKPANCHAL any example token related ?

Comment: you are set in userdefault then you can get token after login or any other screen you get through userdefault.

Comment: userdefault.standard.object(forkey:"token");

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Scenario 1 :** You need to tell to backend developer who made your webservice, that he need to check if TOKEN is valid or not. if token is expired he need to give message code or message that "Token has been expired" and you can check in Response if message code is for expired than you need to navigate your Login screen.
This is best practice.

**Scenario 2 :** If you dont want to Logout from app, and keep app going with new token automatically refresh, tell webservice developer that whenever token will be expired he will return new Token in response field as "Authorization" And from your code side, you need to check in each request whether Authorization contains new token.. if it contains that means you need to replace old token with New one in userdefault.

**Below is my code in Swift3 :**

```
func requestApiCall(_ urlString: String, paramData: NSObject, completionHandler: @escaping (NSDictionary?, NSError?) -> ()) {
    let token =   UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: “token” as String)
    var headersVal = [
        "Authorization": "Bearer "+(token as String),
    ]      
 Alamofire.request(urlString, method: .post, parameters: paramData as? [String : AnyObject],encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: headersVal)

        .responseJSON { response in
            if let authorization = response.response?.allHeaderFields["Authorization"] as? String {

                var newToken : String = authorization
                UserDefaults.standard.set(newToken, forKey: "token")
                UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
            }

            switch response.result {

            case .success(let value):

              if let res = response.result.value {
                     let response = res as! NSDictionary
                     let message = response.object(forKey: "message")!
                     print(message)
                if message as! String ==  "Token has been expired" 
                {
                    self.showLoginScreen()
                }
              }
            completionHandler(value as? NSDictionary, nil)

            case .failure(let error):
                if error._code == -1001 {
                    print("timeout")
                }
                completionHandler(nil, nil)
            }
      }
}
```

Comment: String can not be work                                                                                  if res[“message"].string ==  "Token has been expired"

Comment: You can convert into NSDictionary like :   let response = res as! NSDictionary
                         let message = response.object(forKey: "message”)!
                         print(message)
                    if message as! String ==  "Token has been expired" 
                    {
                        self.showLoginScreen()
                    }
                }
make sure that you use correct key as i used "message"

Comment: @foram what is user open app after `n` days & on dashboard 4 concurrent service call exist & service giving token expired. How you can handle all apis in that case ?

Answer (score 6):

For the `Authorisation Token`, the ideal practice is from server side they need to check, requested API call have `TOKEN` is valid or not. And if the token is not matched or expired, they will provide `HTTP status code` `401`, from Mobile side you need to check the status code first and if you found `401` you need to forcefully logout or re login which takes a new token and you can save it in your `UserDefaults`.

Answer (score 0):

Call service for new token when token expires is unsecure to your app because if token expires and you call service for new token then anyone can access your app or its data. The better way is to logout/sign out the user and ask him to login again.

but if you want to do so then make a method which is user to get new token and call it once you will get token expire code.

but you need to discuss with your backend developer for this new api and accordingly you can move farther

let me know for help . Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I preferred to use `Moya` framework (abstraction under Alamofire) with `PromiseKit`. It makes easier write async code and create dependencies between parts. I wrapped all business logic for sending requests in the class. The main function of the request (`public func register(device: String, type: String) -> Promise<Device>`) returns `Promise` object. In the `recover` block I validate error code and if needed I refresh token and repeat failed request. Code example below:

```
public protocol HttpClientInterface {
...
    func register(device: String, type: String) -> Promise<Device>
...
}

public func register(device: String, type: String) -> Promise<Device> {
    return self.sendRegisterRequest(with: device, type: type)
        .then {
            self.parseRegister(response: $0)
        }
        .recover { lerror -> Promise<Device> in
            guard let error = lerror as? HttpClientError,
                case .server(let value) = error,
                value == ServerError.notAuthenticated,
                let refreshToken = self.credentialsStore.get()?.token?.refreshToken else {
                    throw lerror
            }

            return self.sendRefreshSessionRequest(operatorId: self.operatorId, refreshToken: refreshToken)
                .then { data -> Promise<AuthToken> in
                    return self.parseRefreshSession(data)
                }
                .then { token -> Promise<Device> in
                    self.credentialsStore.update(token: token)
                    return self.register(device: device, type: type)
                }
                .catch { error in
                    if let myError = error as? HttpClientError,
                        case .server(let value) = httpError,
                        value == ServerError.notAuthenticated {
                        self.credentialsStore.accessDenied()
                    }
            }
    }
}

func sendRegisterRequest(with name: String, type: String) -> Promise<Data> {
    return Promise { fulfill, reject in
        self.client.request(.register(device: name, type: type)) {
            self.obtain(result: $0,
                        successStatusCodes: [200, 201],
                        fulfill: fulfill,
                        reject: reject)
        }
    }
}

func parseRegister(response data: Data) -> Promise<Device> {
    return Promise { fulfill, reject in
        if let account = Account(data: data),
            let device = account.devices?.last {
            fulfill(device)
        } else {
            reject(HttpClientError.internalError())
        }
    }
}
```